# When Spark read from the file system does it goes to the driver?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs

I wonder if when Spark ingest data, the data is ingested in the driver and sent to the worker, of Spark instruct the node to read the data from the file system ?

I know that in Spark streaming, with the Kafka source, clearly, the worker nodes read from Kafka. However When reading from the file system, i am unsure as to how it actually works.

case 1

> A - When reading from the file systems assuming that the
> file system is HDFS
>
> A.1 - Does the driver read the file and transfer the data to the worker
> on the go or does he have the worker read the file
>
> A.2 - Are the original partition determine by how HDFS did the its partition ?

Case 2

> B - When from the filesystem where the file system is local one or S3
>
> B.1 - What does happens to the partitioning, does the algorithm change wether we read from HDFS or read from the local file system ? (in the later case, a special algorithm would be used instead on relying on the HDFS partitioning ?
> B.2 - Does the worker participate in reading the Data, even though the data is not partitioned yet ?

How can I clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For file source, `driver program` only read file's metadata.

> The driver looks at file metadata - check that it exists, check what
>   files are in the directory if it's a directory, and check their sizes.
>   It then sends tasks to workers, who do the actual reading of the file
>   contents. The communication is essentially "you read this file,
>   starting at this offset, for this length."